# ASP.NET Gridview Label Text

Tags: asp.net, gridview, label

I have a label which is inside a gridview. I need to get the label's text from javascript.I have a set of say 6 labels..3 From Times ( Hours, Minutes) and same for To Times, all dropdowns. Say I have values already saved as

1. 09-00 to 09-45
2. 09-45 to 10-30
3. 10-30 to 11-15

They are displayed in grid as FromTime and ToTime respectively. My logic is the user should not enter time within this range. The time dropdowns are available in a popup. On click of save button, the popup closes and the selected values are populated in the grid. Could someone suggest me a solution please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you've tried so far. can you give your gridview code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the label have an ID?

You can just grab it using plain JavaScript of JQuery

Ex:

```
$('#IdOfLabel').each(function(){
      var text = $(this).text();
    });
```

Comment: I have a set of say 6 labels..3 From Times ( Hours, Minutes) and same for To Times, all dropdowns. Say I have values already saved as 09-00 to 09-45, 09-45 to 10-30, 10-30 to 11-15. They are displayed in grid as FromTime and ToTime respectively. My logic is the user should not enter time within this range. The time dropdowns are available in a popup. On click of save button, the popup closes and the selected values are populated in the grid.

Comment: Ok I would ensure that they all have unique Ids that you can target like I described above

Comment: No, it is just a single ID. Just the text differs for each row. Looks like I need a For loop.

Comment: Ok I modified the code to grab all the matching elements and iterate over them

Comment: This is the label structure in the grid.
`<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lblFromTimeHour" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTimeHour")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblFromTimeMinute" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTimeMinute")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblToTimeHour" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ToTimeHour")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblToTimeMinute" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ToTimeMinute")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 0):

As `label` is render as `span` so you need to use the following of javascript

```
document.getElementById('<%= lblScore.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Test Value';
document.getElementById('<%= hdnScore.ClientID %>').value = 'Test Value';
```

As it is inside gridview so you may like a particular row lable value.

Comment: Shekhar, I just modified my question. Looks like I need a For loop. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ClientIDMode Property is set to Static in order to access it with the same ID that you gave it. Otherwise the parent control ID will be appended to the label ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
You need RowDataBound event where you can access each row created by asp.net.

**In code behind**

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
       LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("lnk");
       Label lblName= (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblName");                      
       lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "getValue(" + lblName.ClientID + ");"
    }

 }
```

**In javascript**

```
function getValue(lblId)
{
     alert($(lblId).text());
}
```

**OR Try This**

Just add a class name on Update button having ID updateBtn and then try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".updateBtn").click(function (e) {

                var Client = $(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*=lblClientName]").text();
                var Date = $(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*=ltDate]").text();
                alert(Client);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```